# How to implement a translate function in ZK with EL

Tags: methods, el, zk

My webapp has a smart Java translator so I can't use a simple Label-based i18n in ZK. Instead of that,  my smart translator method with two parameters - the key and the language - should be called, but the current language should be get from some webapp scope.

It would be very useful to have an EL function

```
<textbox value="${x:translate('some.i18n.key')}"/>
```

that call my smart translator method with the given String parameter and the current language code from the session.

What I could do is to define a 2-parameter `translate` method

```
 <?xel-method prefix="x" name="translate"
     class="mypackage.Translator"
     signature="java.lang.Class translate(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)"?>
```

and use it as

```
 <textbox value="${x:translate('qqq',sessionScope.get('LANGUAGE'))}"/>
```

but writing the second parameter every times is not a good solution. It can be written a bit shorter as

```
 <textbox value="${x:translate('qqq',LANGUAGE)}"/>
```

or perhaps choose a shorter key instead of `LANGUAGE`, but I am interested in a more compact form.

Is it possible to define such a function that gets this second parameter implicitly? Or somehow to call a method of an object in the session/desktop/page scope from EL?

Answer (score 2):

We use [MVVM](https://books.zkoss.org/zk-mvvm-book/8.0/introduction_of_mvvm.html) pattern with ZK and translation was one area where zk references make their way into your view models. To reduce it's impact we did:

Created a Translator interface:

```
public interface Translator {
    String translate(String key);

    // used where the string to be translation includes placeholders
    // total_qty=Total qty: {1}
    String translate(String key, String... params);
}
```

and a translator implementation:

```
public class ZKTranslator implements Translator {

    @Override
    public String translate(String s) {
        String translation = Labels.getLabel(s);
        if (translation == null)
            return s;
        return translation;
    }

    @Override
    public String translate(String key, String... params) {
        String translation = Labels.getLabel(key, params);
        if (translation == null)
            return key;
        return translation;
    }
}
```

This implementation may reference the session to retrieve a language or maybe (and preferable) the language is passed to ZKTranslator on initialisation.

It is then used as follows. In your view model:

```
public class SomeScreenVM {
    private Translator translator;

    @Init
    public void init() {
        // get language from session possibly
        translator = new ZKTranslator(); // or new ZKTtanslator(language);
    }

    public String translate(String s) {
        return translator.translate(s);
    }
}
```

And in your zul file:

```
<window viewModel="@id('vm')" @init('com.example.SomeScreenVM')>
    <label value="@load(vm.translate('hello'))"/>
</window>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! My app is an old one using GenericForwardComposer and no MVVM. Perhaps I should switch to MVVM, then I can use this approach.

Comment: I would highly recommend switching to MVVM if you have the choice. Of course if you're dealing with legacy code it might be easier said than done.

Answer (score 0):

Custom taglibs is the solution you need.
It exist in ZK :
https://www.zkoss.org/wiki/ZUML_Reference/ZUML/Processing_Instructions/taglib/Custom_Taglib

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, I am not an expert of JSP taglibs, and the rather short and only documentation describes only the public static way.

Comment: Is a static method then unusable for you? if it's a spring bean you need there you can always use the servicelocator(https://www.baeldung.com/java-service-locator-pattern) pattern. I know that there is discussion about if it's a pattern or anti pattern but beside that, it can help you.

Comment: The problem with public static is that I have to supply a LANGUAGE parameter, but I do not want to supply it with each call. So I need some stored state somewhere in the call stack. How would it be possible with custom taglibs.

Comment: Sessions.getCurrent gives you always the current session.

Answer (score 0):

I can (miss)use the map support of EL in order to call a non-static, one-parameter method of an object.

First, I need a translator object implementing `java.util.Map` that can translate a String in its `get()` method:

```
    public class Translator implements Map<String, String> {

        private String language;

        public Translator(String language) {
            super();
            this.language = language;
        }

        @Override
        public String get(Object arg0) {
            return translate(arg0.toString(), language);
        }
        ...
    }
```

Then I can put a translator into the desktop scope and use it in EL:

```
<zscript>
    desktopScope.put("tr",new mypackage.Translator(sessionScope.get("language")));
</zscript>

 <textbox value="${tr.some_key}"/>
 <textbox value="${tr['some.hierarchical.key']}"/>
```

It is really not a clear solution, but makes the work with ZUL files rather simple.